# Developing an app with 100's of EditFields and TextFields

Tags: android, android-studio, android-textwatcher

I am developing an app with 100's of textfields and editfields. In a lot of them I have used textwatcher to listen to changes and update other textfields. I dont have much choice on this matter as a lot of fields are dependent on each other. But the app is encountering a lot of performance issues. It freezes a lot. Can I get some tips on developing apps with insane number of textfields. I think all the textwatchers I use is slowing down the ui thread.

```
  //Business Operating Cost
        TextWatcher businessOperatingCostTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
            private double edtTaxPayment = 0.0;
            private double txtPaymentBusinessLoan = 0.0;
            private double edtOtherBusiness = 0.0;
            private double edtBasicServices = 0.0;
            private double edtTransport = 0.0;
            private double edtLocalRental = 0.0;
            private double edtSalaries = 0.0;
            private double unforeseen = 0.0;

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if (mCashFlowBinding.edtSalaries != null && mCashFlowBinding.edtSalaries.length() != 0) {
                    edtSalaries = Double.parseDouble(mCashFlowBinding.edtSalaries.getText().toString());
                }
                if (mCashFlowBinding.edtLocalRental != null && mCashFlowBinding.edtLocalRental.length() != 0) {
                    edtLocalRental = Double.parseDouble(mCashFlowBinding.edtLocalRental.getText().toString());
                }
                if (mCashFlowBinding.edtTransport != null && mCashFlowBinding.edtTransport.length() != 0) {
                    edtTransport = Double.parseDouble(mCashFlowBinding.edtTransport.getText().toString());
                }
                if (mCashFlowBinding.edtBasicServices != null && mCashFlowBinding.edtBasicServices.length() != 0) {
                    edtBasicServices = Double.parseDouble(mCashFlowBinding.edtBasicServices.getText().toString());
                }
                if (mCashFlowBinding.edtOtherBusiness != null && mCashFlowBinding.edtOtherBusiness.length() != 0) {
                    edtOtherBusiness = Double.parseDouble(mCashFlowBinding.edtOtherBusiness.getText().toString());
                }
                if (mCashFlowBinding.txtPaymentBusinessLoan != null && mCashFlowBinding.txtPaymentBusinessLoan.length() != 0) {
                    txtPaymentBusinessLoan = Double.parseDouble(mCashFlowBinding.txtPaymentBusinessLoan.getText().toString());
                }
                if (mCashFlowBinding.edtTaxPayment != null && mCashFlowBinding.edtTaxPayment.length() != 0) {
                    edtTaxPayment = Double.parseDouble(mCashFlowBinding.edtTaxPayment.getText().toString());
                }
                if (mCashFlowBinding.txtUnforseen != null && mCashFlowBinding.txtUnforseen.length() != 0) {
                    unforeseen = Double.parseDouble(mCashFlowBinding.txtUnforseen.getText().toString());
                }
                double resultSum = (edtTaxPayment + txtPaymentBusinessLoan + edtOtherBusiness + edtBasicServices + edtTransport + edtLocalRental + edtSalaries + unforeseen);

                if (!Double.isNaN(resultSum) && !Double.isInfinite(resultSum)) {
                    mCashFlowBinding.txtBusinessOperatingCost1.setText(String.valueOf(resultSum));
                } else {
                    mCashFlowBinding.txtBusinessOperatingCost1.setText("0.0");
                }
            }
        };

        mCashFlowBinding.edtSalaries.addTextChangedListener(businessOperatingCostTextWatcher);
        mCashFlowBinding.edtLocalRental.addTextChangedListener(businessOperatingCostTextWatcher);
        mCashFlowBinding.edtTransport.addTextChangedListener(businessOperatingCostTextWatcher);
        mCashFlowBinding.edtBasicServices.addTextChangedListener(businessOperatingCostTextWatcher);
        mCashFlowBinding.edtOtherBusiness.addTextChangedListener(businessOperatingCostTextWatcher);
        mCashFlowBinding.txtPaymentBusinessLoan.addTextChangedListener(businessOperatingCostTextWatcher);
        mCashFlowBinding.edtTaxPayment.addTextChangedListener(businessOperatingCostTextWatcher);
        mCashFlowBinding.txtUnforseen.addTextChangedListener(businessOperatingCostTextWatcher);
```

Comment: only one `TextWatcher` is activated at a time, so this might not be the reason. check if there are other work you are doing in the main thread

Answer (score 0):

What you could do to ease the Main UI Thread:

Expose some LiveData of your ViewModel to your View and just call `postValue` in your TextWatcher. It then quickly releases.

In the LiveData observer you can then handle the processing on a separate Thread and send the result again to a LiveData object `finalOperstingCosts`.

In the observer of this LiveData you then set the Text to the field.

This way you never have long running tasks on the Main Thread.